# Conditional rendering between 3 page component or navigation, how to?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, conditional-statements, rendering, conditional-rendering

I want to know if conditional rendering between 3 page component is a professional way or should I do it different ? 
**Header** is the navbar but I want it disappear when **signIn** or **signUp** page components will show.

With SignUp for now its like that -

```js
 //userAccount is a Boolean 

return (
    <div> {userAccount ? (
        <SignUp  />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Header/>
           <Switch>
             <Route exact path='/'>
                <Home />
           </Route>
           <Route exact path='/search'>
            <Search/>
          </Route>
              </> )
        <div/>
```

When I add a **SignIn** page component I will have 2 conditions. I think it will look ugly & unprofessional.
Should I do an Auth Component where SignUp and SignIn will be shown - each by an authentication  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'; to navigate with different pages for react

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).